# software that listens to http posts

Tags: http

i'm debugging some hidden http posts on my website. can you refer a free application that shows a console of the http posts happening on my PC? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) plugin for Firefox works pretty well for this task. [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) can also do it, along with a whole lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is exactly what you are looking for, if you are looking for a stand-alone program.  If you want a Firefox plugin [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966), or [Live Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) are both good.

Comment: I've found LiveHeaders to be buggy.Specifically, it had a problem where if you uploaded a file and had LiveHeaders installed, that file would then be locked on your machine until you closed FireFox. The issue may be fixed now, but I none-the-less lost trust in the product, and I think HTTPFox does what it does, better.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) for Firefox.